# Why am I getting this error in Gmail - "You have reached a limit for sending mail."

Tags: gmail

I have been having problems with undeliverable mail with the following error messages. This is just regular email reply to a single recipient. (recipient emailed me first)

What can I do to fix this? After trying about 20 times, I get a "Y**ou have reached a limit for sending mail.**" message, which is ridiculous.

edit:

this is 20 times to 1 email address each time. Some emails were to myself (testing the issue) and others were to 3 different email addresses. I never send more than 10 emails x 1 recipient a day in total.

I am using gmail's send-email-as feature to send mail from a different domain. This error occurs regardless of whether i send from @gmail.com or @my-domain.com

edit end:

Delivery to the following recipient failed permanently:

```
 <removed>@gmail.com
```

Technical details of permanent failure:
Message rejected.  See https://support.google.com/mail/answer/69585 for more information.

---- Original message -----

```
X-Received: by 10.31.152.85 with SMTP id a82mr2304710vke.47.1467976082104;
        Fri, 08 Jul 2016 04:08:02 -0700 (PDT)
Return-Path: <<my-name>@<my-domain>.com>
Received: from mail-vk0-f50.google.com (mail-vk0-f50.google.com. [209.85.213.50])
        by smtp.gmail.com with ESMTPSA id 36sm1943503uad.5.2016.07.08.04.08.01
        for <<removed>@gmail.com>
        (version=TLS1_2 cipher=ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 bits=128/128);
        Fri, 08 Jul 2016 04:08:01 -0700 (PDT)
Received: by mail-vk0-f50.google.com with SMTP id v6so53151831vkb.2
        for <<removed>@gmail.com>; Fri, 08 Jul 2016 04:08:01 -0700 (PDT)
X-Gm-Message-State: ALyK8tLv1zV+ieOp9BR++9rREaCIjrHEa+LMysEvyYhcvbb+drYAjHP8FlyB9X6CeZ1d/srGA9jsvIakRAC7Sg==
MIME-Version: 1.0
X-Received: by 10.31.63.210 with SMTP id m201mr2356728vka.23.1467976081637;
 Fri, 08 Jul 2016 04:08:01 -0700 (PDT)
Received: by 10.176.3.232 with HTTP; Fri, 8 Jul 2016 04:08:01 -0700 (PDT)
Date: Fri, 8 Jul 2016 19:08:01 +0800
X-Gmail-Original-Message-ID: <CALEbxg5oMRFV9pH7_dnOtXecaiTiLA+f=RbZoESCo+zeg2EFJw@mail.gmail.com>
Message-ID: <CALEbxg5oMRFV9pH7_dnOtXecaiTiLA+f=RbZoESCo+zeg2EFJw@mail.gmail.com>
Subject:
From: <removed> <<my-name>@<my-domain>.com>
To: <removed>@gmail.com
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=001a114dab5ce2d4e905371dd05c
```

Comment: 20 times of what? How many email addresses per email?

Comment: This seems confusing to me as you have **`From: <removed> <<my-name>@<my-domain>.com>`** and then **`To: <removed>@gmail.com`**. An SMTP NDR bounce back indicating "**`You have reached a limit for sending mail.`**" to me would indicate that the limit is on the `<removed> <<my-name>@<my-domain>.com>` side and not the Gmail side. Therefore, check your limits of your email account on that domain rather than Gmail since that's where you are sending from if it's not also a gmail.com email account. I'd say you need to provide some more detail to clarify all the specifics of your setup and so forth.

Comment: Gmail has a send-email-as feature, and thats what I am using. Do note that the error occurs regardless of which email address I send from (gmail AND my own domain). My domain service is paid and will not run into some kind of limit.

Comment: Update: tried 24 hours later and the (identical) email sends as expected. When the issue first occurred it was the first email i sent that day.

Answer (score 3):

Gmail has a daily limit. Gmail is not an email blasting service. You will need to contract an independent email server from a hosting company, or send your email through an email opt-in service like mail-chimp.

Either you have sent spam in the past or detected as currently sending and your daily sending limit has been reduced.

GMAIL is not a CORPORATE or BUSINESS grade email service. You may have legitimate BUSINESS needs that GMAIL is not equipped to handle. I see this all the time with my clients and they have to end up using an independent mail server.

Comment: The question does not seem to imply that he is planning to blast emails. Most likely, he just tried to send a failing email too many times.

Comment: I see this everyday in the gmail support forums, even the support link gmail gives to him , implys it. It begins by saying  "Here at Gmail, we work very hard to fight spam."

Comment: Might be worth adding in [this link](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/22839?hl=en) with the related info. The bit about "or if you send a large number of undeliverable messages" might be particularly relevant.

Comment: I have never sent more than 10 unique emails x 1 recipient per email a day. How much is too much? In this case I am -replying- to an email someone sent me...

Comment: You account might have gotten hacked and you are not realizing that someone is using your account to send spam. So you are getting limited because of that. I recommend to change your password and activate two-factor authentication.

Answer (score 2):

You mention that you had sent the same email about 20 times and reached a limit. Gmail says that its sending limit is about 500 recipients or a large number of failed requests per day: https://support.google.com/mail/answer/22839?hl=en At 20 failed attempts, that seems to me to be a large number of failed attempts.

If your email fails, it may be okay to make a small edit and then try it again, but by 20 times, I can't imagine that there would be much new that you could be attempting, and so maybe at that point, you should be contacting gmail for more information, as their link suggests.

As to the original cause of the rejection, only gmail could say for certain. They don't publish their algorithm, and they don't seem to make it very clear. I see that you have no subject in the header. If you did not delete it before posting, then that could be a problem. There are too many potential issues to list them all here, but I would recommend contacting gmail directly for more information.